# Observing array attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an attribute in my model that is an array (of floats) and is serialized and returned as such by my Rails backend. I then take the field, (`monthlyData` in this example) and plot it using a D3-based component that I wrote.

```
{{bar-chart dataBinding="monthlyData" height=75 width =300}}
```

Everything works fine, except when the data changes. In the JS of my component I have an observer that observes the `data` attribute of the component and re-renders the view, however this observer is not fired if my model changes. It does, however fire if I set the `monthlyData` field directly, e.g. by doing `this.get('model').set('data', [1,2,3,4,5])` in my controller.

I have tried both not specifying an attribute type (i.e. in my model specifying `monthlyData: DS.attr()` and using a custom array transform (in the hope that the returned Ember.Array would be observer-friendly):

```
App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Ember.A(serialized);
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized.toArray();
  }
});
```

I'm using Ember 1.3 beta 1 and Ember Data 1.0.0 beta 4. What's the best practice around using arrays as data types and how do I make them observable?

Comment: Why are you re-rendering the view? Are you sure that the model has updated?

Comment: I guess updating would be more accurate. I don't re-render, just update the height of the bars in my chart to reflect the new data. That code works fine - but the problem is that that observer function is never triggered (unless I specifically `set` the data of the array as described above.

Comment: How is the model being updated? Are you using `save()`? Also, when the model saves, is your rails app involved via an API?

Comment: I'm basically polling my server for updates on my model using setInterval() to reload() my model. So the changes to the data do not happen on the front end, but is done by rails. Any other attribute changes (strings, floats) show up properly, but the observer for the array is not triggered for some reason.

Comment: Is your server responding with JSON? Are you sure that there are changes being made to the model on the server?

Comment: Yes it's JSON and the response is as expected (it includes changes).

Comment: Can you post the `monthlyData` method for computing the property, or is that a model property?

Comment: That's a model property that gets returned by my rails backend (it's an array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to observe `data.@each` instead of `data` to monitor Arrays.